# Redirecting simple big problem

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

i'm a little worried here.

I'm trying to redirect EVERYONE that access my site to a specific webpage, and nothing is working! Currently i'm trying this code:

```
function redirect_this() {
    wp_redirect( 'http://www.myawesomesite.com/here.html', 301 );
    exit;
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_this');
```

And the page always show

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...
```

This is driving me crazy.

By the way, i've created a plugin to hold this code. So this code is in a single plugin file.

Comment: Could you show the full warning? The part after "headers already sent by ..." could be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Better use a .htaccess redirect so you avoid even loading WP:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com [R=301,L]
```

If you want to keep the path after the domain, (e.g. www.olddomain.com/mypage -> www.newdomain.com/mypage) replace the last line with:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Save three bytes: `RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

template_redirect is happening after the headers are sent, try hooking redirect_this into wp_loaded instead:

```
add_action('wp_loaded', 'redirect_this');
```

You'll have to be a little more deliberate in your redirect_this function to specifically target the page you want to be redirecting, or else everything will redirect to that page, do something like this:

```
function redirect_this() {
    if ( is_page('slug-of-page-you-wish-to-redirect') ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.myawesomesite.com/here.html', 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `template_redirect` hook is not happening after headers are sent normally. I've been able to do successful `wp_redirect()`s via that hook. In this case `wp_loaded` works as well, though.

Comment: `template_redirect` is not called after headers are sent (in the "usual"). If headers are already sent by `template_redirect` there is a problem.